# Verilog - How to plug values from an output register in a testbench module?

Tags: verilog, test-bench

So we were provided with a sequential module in Verilog and have been tasked to create a testbench to show the difference between non-blocking and blocking assignments.

Provided code:

```
module sequential_module (A, B, C, D, clk);
input clk;

output A, B, C, D;
reg A, B, C, D;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
   A = B;
   B = A;
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
   C <= D;
   D <= C;
end

endmodule
```

I can't seem to plug any values to any of the variables (A, B, C, D) in the testbench because I get the "Illegal output or inout port connection" error.

The testbench I've managed to create:

```
module testbench_sequential;
reg clk;
wire A, B, C, D;

sequential_module test(A, B, C, D, clk);
always
   #5 clk = ~clk;
 
initial
   begin
      clk = 1'b0; 
      $display ("Simulating output for Activity 3a");
      $monitor ($time,,, "clk = %b A = %b B = %b C = %b D = %b ", clk, A, B, C, D);      
      #25 $finish;
   end

endmodule
```

The only output I get from the testbench above is that the clock seems to be working, but the other variables have "Don't care" values on them (1'bx). I'm sort of new to using this application and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You defined all your signals (A-D) as outputs.
2. In your assignments e.g. `A = B` (it should be `<=`), all regs have actually no value. You didn't initialize them. Thus, they are showed as `1'bx` in your testbench.

To achieve what you want you can simply modify the declaration of your regs, e.g.:

```
reg A = 1'b0, B = 1'b1, C = 1'b0, D = 1'b1;
```

[The result](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/rwS):

> Simulating output for Activity 3a
>
> 0  clk = 0 A = 0 B = 1 C = 0 D = 1
>
> 5  clk = 1 A = 1 B = 1 C = 1 D = 0
>
> 10  clk = 0 A = 1 B = 1 C = 1 D = 0
>
> 15  clk = 1 A = 1 B = 1 C = 0 D = 1
>
> 20  clk = 0 A = 1 B = 1 C = 0 D = 1

Comment: this might not be synthesizable.

Comment: this might work for simulation only, I'm not really sure if there is an FPGA that can initialize a register with a value different from 0.